# Expo SDK 43, No suitable URL request handler found for ph-upload://

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

After upgrade Expo SDK version from 41.0.0 to 43.0.0 I got a problem with uploading images to server. Error description: `No suitable URL request handler found for ph-upload://A354049E-57C1-4478-B5C0-1DF56886F1AD`. What I have noticed is that in error description I see `ph-upload://` but if I log my photo it contains this: `"uri":"ph://A354049E-57C1-4478-B5C0-1DF56886F1AD","name":"IMG_3702.JPG","type":"photo"`. The difference is `ph-upload://` and `ph://`.

This is my code:

```
const onSubmitPress = async () => {
        await setLoadingIndicator(true);
        let formData = new FormData();

        formData.append('title', textTitle);
        formData.append('description', textDescription);
        formData.append('latitude', latitude);
        formData.append('longitude', longitude);
        formData.append('photoAuthor', photoAuthor);
        formData.append('textAuthor', textAuthor);
        formData.append('landscapeType', landscapeType);
        formData.append('region', region);
        route.params?.data?.map((image, index) =>
        formData.append(`photo[]`, {
                uri: image.uri,
                name: image.filename,
                type: image.mediaType,
            }));
        route.params.data = undefined;
        const jwtToken = await SecureStore.getItemAsync('JWT');
        let responseTypes = await fetch('https://beautiful-places.ru/api/upload_place', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data;',
                'API-Access-Key': '******',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + jwtToken
            },
            body: formData
        })
}
```

Before upgrade everything worked as expected.

Comment: I'm having the same issue upgrading from SDK 41 to 43, did you solve the issue?

Comment: Hi, @hancho! Try to check type of the media via mime library : type: mime.getType(image.uri) This should help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case I provided incorrect type of image, it somehow worked with expo ver. 41, but in ver. 43 it doesn't work. This code works fine:

```
import mime from "mime"; //mime library helps to check type of image.

 let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('title', textTitle);
        formData.append('description', textDescription);
        formData.append('latitude', latitude);
        formData.append('longitude', longitude);
        formData.append('photoAuthor', photoAuthor);
        formData.append('textAuthor', textAuthor);
        formData.append('landscapeType', landscapeType);
        formData.append('region', region);
        photos?.map((image, index) =>
            formData.append(`photo[]`, {
                uri: image.uri,
                name: image.uri.substring(image.uri.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, image.uri.length),
                type: mime.getType(image.uri), // after this change problem has gone
            })
    );
        const jwtToken = await SecureStore.getItemAsync('JWT');
        let responseTypes = await fetch('https://some-url/api/upload_place', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                'API-Access-Key': 'SomeKey',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + jwtToken
            },
            body: formData
        })
```